# Symfony 2 - Data tables jquery

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

In my project I have three databases. I am using this 3 databases to create one specific object.
This object is not linked at any database.

I created my function and I returned my result as follow:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Blabla:index.html.twig', array('result' => $arr));
```

And here is the way I'm using my collection of objects in my twig template:

```
{% for res in result %}
    <tr class="{{ cycle(['even', 'odd'], loop.index) }}">
        <td>{{ res.codeCommercial }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.codePostal }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.ouvertureCompte }}</td>
        <td>{{ res.nomClient }}</td>
    </tr>           
{% endfor %}
```

I found [this link](https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle#soon--support-of-odm-mongodb) about using datatables with jQuery.

I don't really known how I can use that because I don't send Entity linked with database but a collection of object.

I am trying [this link](http://www.nicolas-verhoye.com/mettez-de-la-vie-dans-vos-tableaux-avec-jquery-datatables.html#.Ump9K_m9UQp) but javascript is not interpreted :(.

My question is: How can I use datatables without entity and how js is interpreted ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does your Twig template prints a proper table? In that case, just use `$('#table').dataTable()` (and of course include all js/css files) to enable Datatables.